# How to alter colum from varchar to geometry

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a varchar column that stores locations in format: `{"coordinates":[25.7989,65.4364],"type":"Point"}` (1 location in 1 row). How to alter this column to `geometry` type?

Comment: SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to:

- add new column with the new date type
- migrate the data to the column
- drop the initial column
- rename the new column with the dropped column name

Of course, if you have indexes or constraints on the original column you will need to drop them first and later recreated.

The following is example of doing so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Test];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    [point] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([point])
VALUES ('{"coordinates":[25.7989,65.4364],"type":"Point"}');

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]
ADD [point_temp] GEOMETRY;

GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Test]
SET [point_temp] = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(J.value, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', ' ') + ')', 0) 
FROM [dbo].[Test] T
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([point]) J
WHERE J.[key] = 'coordinates';

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]
DROP COLUMN [point];

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Test.point_temp', 'point', 'COLUMN';  

GO

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test]
```

Comment: Should not that `CROSS APPLY` be working with `point` rather than having the JSON appear directly?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, it should. Thanks.